# Spark Model Methods crash in IF statement

Tags: c#-4.0, nancy, spark-view-engine

I am using some methods from my viewdata model in Spark, but it doesn't work properly. I thought it was working previously, but it appears to be crashing. Am I doing something wrong that I am unaware of?

```
        <if condition='model.GetServerRunning()' >
            <h1><a href="#">IT WORKS</a></h1>
        </if>
```

Also, can multiple classes be used from code in a Spark file, or can only the one be passed `<viewdata model="namespace.class">`? I see stuff on the Spark documentation like `<viewdata currentProduct="Product"/>` but I don't understand what that is pulling from.

Answer (score 1):

The Spark `if` statement above should be written like this:

```
<if condition='Model.GetServerRunning()' >
    <h1><a href="#">IT WORKS</a></h1>
</if>
```

Notice the capital 'M' in `Model`. Think of `model` and `Model` as reserved words in Spark, where the first (lower case) is used in a `<viewdata>` tag to define the strongly typed view, and the second (upper case) is used  as a reference to the instance of that object type which can be used throughout your view. But only one instance of `Model` can be declared per view.

The second thing you mention is the loosely typed `ViewData` `object Dictionary` in MVC2, or you could use `ViewBag` in MVC3 which utilizes the new `dynamic` types. What you're doing in your second snippit, is pulling out an instance of an `object` called `Product` and assigning it to a local variable called `currentProduct`. From there you can use it as you want. This was only done to support the `ViewData` construct that came with MVC, not because it's actually a good design. The more widely accepted correct design would be to have a single model per view which is what the `model` syntax provides.

There are obviously edge cases where you might use both, but I generally stick to one model per view and has served me well on many sites, and I can't say I've ever been forced into a position where I need to fill up the `ViewData Dictionary` with arbitrary data. If you do, it's usually an indicator of a smell in your viewModel design.

Hope that helps,
Rob